# Notation diversity

Tags: notation

This morning I had a brief discussion about different notations of trigonometric functions in Europe, so I looked for an online resource dealing with these diversities in mathematical notation. I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5165) treating the issue. It links to a website called [Notation census](http://wiki.math-bridge.org/display/ntns/Home) which aims to deal with the diversity by listing the variations in the notation around the world. Still, I find it quite hard to browse the site and feel that lot of things are still not included in its database. Therefore, my question is: do you know of a book or a website compiling these differences in notation in which one can find the most of the non-orthodox symbols and abbreviations used in the world?

Comment: I would add that differences exist not only across different (geographical) locations, but across different cultures. For example, I have seen different attitudes towards notation for identity matrix among linear algebraists and others (algebraic geometeres, dynamical system-ists). 

Comment: The website for the Mathematical Notation Census at `math-bridge.org` seems to be down. It redirects to `notations.hoplahup.net`, and then I receive a "502 Bad Gateway" error.

Answer (score 3):

Christine Müller has collected a variety of examples to illustrate the diversity of notation, in the [Survey on Mathematical Notations](https://kwarc.info/people/cmueller/papers/ntn-techreport.pdf). Diversity exists because of distinct reasons:

- level of expertise ($a\div b$ in elementary school, versus
  $\frac{a}{b}$ in high school)
- individual styles ($A\subseteq B$ or $A\subseteqq B$)
- cultural habits (anglo-saxon $(0,1]$ versus french $]0,1]$, or german 0,5 versus english 0.5; my personal example is https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5644/why-did-i-learn-to-write-the-base-of-the-logarithm-differently-from-the-rest-of )
- area of application ($i$ in mathematics is $j$ in engineering, $\neq$ in mathematics is $!\!\!=$ in computer science, $\bar{z}$ in mathematics is $z^\ast$ in physics, $A^\ast$ in mathematics is $A^\dagger$ in physics – to no end of confusion ...)
- mistakes (arcsinh instead of arsinh)

This all addresses notation that is diverse but still commonly used. For non-orthodox notation I could offer Richard Feynman's trigonometric notation:

[image]


> While I was doing all this trigonometry [as a teenager], I didn't like
> the symbols for sine, cosine, tangent, and so on. To me, "sin f"
> looked like s times i times n times f! So I invented another symbol,
> like a square root sign, that was a sigma with a long arm sticking out
> of it, and I put the f underneath. For the tangent it was a tau with
> the top of the tau extended, and for the cosine I made a kind of
> gamma, but it looked a little bit like the square root sign.
>
> Now the
> inverse sine was the same sigma, but left-to-right reflected so that
> it started with the horizontal line with the value underneath, and
> then the sigma. *That* was the inverse sine, NOT $\sin^{-1} f$ – that
> was crazy! They had that in books! To me, $\sin^{-1}$ meant 1/sine,
> the reciprocal. So my symbols were better.
>
> I didn't like f(x) – that looked to me like f times X. I also didn't
> like dy/dx-you have a tendency to cancel the d's, so I made a different
> sign, something like an & sign. For logarithms it was a big L extended
> to the right, with the thing you take the log of inside, and so on.
>
> I thought my symbols were just as good, if not better, than the regular
> symbols – it doesn't make any difference *what* symbols you use but I
> discovered later that it *does* make a difference. Once when I was
> explaining something to another kid in high school, without thinking I
> started to make these symbols, and he said, "What the hell are those?"
> I realized then that if I'm going to talk to anybody else, I'll have
> to use the standard symbols, so I eventually gave up my own symbols.

from: [Surely You're Joking, Mr. Feynman!](https://books.google.nl/books?id=_gA_DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT21)

Comment: There's also the matter of whether $A \subset B$ means the same as $A \subseteq B$ or as $A \subsetneq B$.